# Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) with continuous value?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I wonder if LDA can be supervised with continuous value.
If not, what are the closest variants for such applications?

Comment: Linear regression, see second paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis.